# check if country code contains given string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

below is my code

```
years_list = set() 
for i in range(0,indicators_csv.shape[0]) :
    if (indicators_csv['CountryCode'].str.contains('USA')) :
       years_list.append(indicator_csv.iloc[i].Year)
```

Here indicator_csv is a csv file having column as 'CountryCode'
when run this I got following error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

on if line.  I also tried

```
if (indicators_csv['CountryCode'] == ('USA'))
```

but getting same error.

I googled it i found some answer related to numbers or and or but nothing like this I found.

Comment: indicators_csv is a panda series?

Comment: @saravanakumarv  no its panda dataframe

Comment: the error is throwing up because you are trying to use a series of boolean value in a IF clause where it expects single boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to avoid iterating over `pandas` objects as much as possible - it's mich slower than the native vectorised operations. Your issue is that `indicators_csv['CountryCode'].str.contains('USA')` checks if `'USA'` is in `'CountryCode'` for every row, so you end up with a column of True and False entries.

What you want to do instead is filter the dataframe to just those rows that contain `'USA'` and then convert the `'Year'` column from that frame to a list.  You can do all of this directly in one operation (split across two lines for readability)

```
years_list = indicators_csv[indicators_csv['CountryCode'].str.contains('USA')]\
                           ['Year'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly and you want to iterate over the df instead of using a vectorised approach, you can use:

```
years_list = []
for index, row in indicators_csv.iterrows():
    if ('USA' in row['CountryCode']):
        years_list.append(row['Year'])
```

Input:

```
  CountryCode  Year
0         USA  1980
1          UK  1990
2          FR  1984
3         USA  2000
```

Output:

```
[1980L, 2000L]
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is throwing up because you are trying to use a series of boolean value in a IF clause where it expects single boolean.